# Proof a Deduction with Assumptions

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I came across this exercise while studying the deduction theorem in logic:

> Prove the following expression using calculus with assumptions:
> ~( p ∧ q ), ~p → r, ~q → s ⇒ r ∨ s

This is how I tried to solve it:

```
 1. ~( p ∧ q )                premise 1
 2. ~p → r                    premise 2
 3. ~q → s                    premise 3
 4. ├ ~(A ∧ B) → ~A ∨ ~B      De Morgan's Laws
 5. ~p ∨ ~q                   MP 1,4
 6. r ∨ s                     MP 2,3,5
```

I know the step 6 is incorrect, first because I can't deduce ~q nor ~p, maybe that should be my assumption, right? But even if I assume `~p` and `~q` (hence `r` and `s`), I can't figure out how to connect the expression `~( p ∧ q )` with `r ∨ s`. How would you do this proof?

Comment: Try disjunction elimination

Comment: Details depend on the rules of your proof system... Natural Deduction? (in this case it is quite easy).

Comment: If instead you have axioms, from $(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)$ you have to use axioms for Disjunction: $A \to B \lor A$ and $A \to A \lor B$ with $(A \to C) \to (((B \to C) \to ((A \lor B) \to C)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA do you mean A → A∨B  and  B → A∨B, right? Is  A∨B→A a valid axiom?